# How to set user-specific routes in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I have an Angular 6 app that uses provider information to determine the functionality (channels) of the app. I am working with an object that I receive from a server after a user logs on and that provides me with boolean values for the respective channels.

```
providerInfos = {
  channels: {
    a: true,
    b: true,
    c: true
  }
}
```

In the index.html I have

```
<base href="/home/">
```

and in my app-routing.module I have

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'a', pathMatch: 'full' }, // Set /a as "start page".
  { path: 'a', component: AComponent, runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always' },
  { path: 'a/:id', component: ADetailsComponent },
  { path: 'b', component: BComponent },
  { path: 'c', component: CComponent }
];
```

So when the app is initialized, A is loaded (somewhere.io/home/a). This was good so far, but due to a further development of the app it turned out that A can't be given as a channel either. This has created a problem for me which I have not been able to solve yet. The more I think about it and look at my code, the more I think that my previous approach is basically wrong.

When initializing the app I want to be able to display B or C as the first or only view (somewhere.io/home/whatever), if A is not part of the app's functionality. In principle I want to provide the app with routes according to the functionality defined for a user via his provider information, at least with

```
path: '', redirectTo: 'whatever', pathMatch: 'full'
```

if only one functionality is given.

I can customize the functionality via the provider information, so that the menu in the sidebar is customized and I make the components that are not part of the functionality inaccessible via *ngIf, if someone gets the idea to enter paths in the URL bar. But I can't manage to adjust the routes accordingly.

How would you deal with this problem. Is there best practice for this?

Comment: Have you considered a route guard that redirects if required?

Comment: @ Kurt Hamilton: Thanks for your hint! I just had a look at route guards and I will think about the use of route guards again, but I think that they can't solve my problem completely. They are especially helpful when I want to deny a user access to a route.  This is also the case, but the big challenge is that I want to customize the first view `path: '', redirectTo: 'whatever' ...`, if it is not component A and I am especially looking for a way to exchange the entire routes array according to the user type, so that the full functionality is "invisible" and only needed routes are existing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a route guard to achieve this functionality. Not only do route guards prevent a user from accessing a route, they also allow you to tell the router where to navigate to by returning a `UrlTree`.

Given the following routes:

```js
const routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'a', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'a', component: ComponentA, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'b', component: ComponentB }
];
```

I can set up my `AuthGuard` as follows:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router, private userService: UserService) {
  }

  canActivate() : boolean | UrlTree {
    const user = this.userService.getCurrentUser();

    const userCanAccessA = false; // TODO: implement
    if (userCanAccessA) {
      return true;
    }

    // redirect to /b
    return this.router.parseUrl('/b');
  }
}
```

I am not recommending this example as a good implementation, I am merely demonstrating the capabilities of a route guard. Your requirements will determing how your routes are structured, and what the redirect logic is.

It can be tempting to make guards do a lot of work. Instead, I would keep each guard focussed on performing a specific task. You can then compose guard logic by combining guards if required.

Note that in my demo below, component A is never constructed, since `AuthGuard` prevents access before routing occurs.

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gxsb3m

Comment: @ Kurt Hamilton I have solved the problem for now via a simple route guard, because an urlTree can only be returned from [Angular 7+](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/new-in-angular-v7-1-updates-to-the-router-fd67d526ad05). In the end it seems to me that the only solution is to upgrade to a higher Angular version.